# AngularJS: how to undo any last change in the document

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to use $watch in order to create an undo functionality which I could use to undo any last change in the view?
For example, I have multiple input fields, ng-includes on demand etc - what would be the easiest and most efficient way of implementing Undo functionality?

I was thinking about pushing any change on the view to an array, and in case of undoing() simply deleting the last item from that array and serving the array again, though not sure if there is another, better way of doing that in angular. Any tips?

Comment: do angular.copy on original object, and the on reset - just replace updated object with orignal/copied object

Answer (score 1):

You could use the LazyJsonUndoRedo:

https://github.com/azazdeaz/LazyJsonUndoRedo

http://dailyjs.com/2014/07/18/lazy-json-undo/

From the readme:

A 'drop in' history handler with automatic undo/redo functionality for nested javascript objects, using ES6 Object.observe() or Polymer shim.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @War10ck thank you for helping me giving a good answer, but i don't see, why is this answer "does not provide an answer to the question". From my point of view it's pointing out to a library witch is perfectly fulfill all the needs mentioned in the question. What did i miss?